# Prevent Click on Window When Binding a Click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, web-applications, window

I have a click event on an element that when clicked binds another click event on the window which has a callback of function with a reverse operation. In this case it's simply a menu like an OS menu where you click on a menu and then when you click on a menu item or outside the menu it closes the menu. Think right click menu, Ubuntu/Mac the top menu bar, etc.

My issue is that because im binding a click event on the window on click it's triggering the window click also. How can I "delay" it so its all "future" clicks? If you look for the `app().debug('closed/clicked?','console');` you'll see two, and they *both* fire on click...

So my code looks like:

```
      {..code...}
      actionMenu: function(action,item){
        if(action == 'open'){
          $(window).bind('click.contextMenus',app().actionMenu('close'));
          $(item).addClass('active').find('ol').css({display:'block',top:$(item).outerHeight()+'px'});
        }
        else if(action == 'close'){
          app().debug('closed?','console');
          $('#menu .active').removeClass('active');
          $('#menu > ol > li ol').css({display:'none'});
          $(window).unbind('click.contextMenus');
        }
      },
      {..code...}
```

And:

```
$('#menu > ol > li').click(function(e){
    if($(this).find('ol').is(':visible')){
      app().actionMenu('close');
    }
    else{
      app().debug('clicked?','console');
      app().actionMenu('open',this);
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding on window, you can bind on `<body>` (I'm not sure whether or not stopping propagation would work when binding on window)

```
$('body').bind('click.contextMenus',app().actionMenu('close'));
```

and then you can prevent event propagation on your menu's onclick to stop it from firing the parent elements' onclick

```
$('#menu > ol > li').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($(this).find('ol').is(':visible')){
      app().actionMenu('close');
    }
    else{
      app().debug('clicked?','console');
      app().actionMenu('open',this);
      return false;
    }
  });
```

**EDIT**

I had not looked closely enough. This is the line that's the issue:

```
$(window).bind('click.contextMenus',app().actionMenu('close'));
```

You're actually calling the actionMenu() function there. You need to do this instead:

```
$(window).bind('click.contextMenus', function() { app().actionMenu('close') } );
```

Comment: Try adding a `return false;` after the `app().actionMenu('close');`

Comment: YES! Thank you. Duh... can't believe i missed that. Thanks again tho!